# Unable to get image from postman Form-data using java azure functions to store Blob-Storage

Tags: java, azure-functions, postman, azure-blob-storage, form-data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syq7L.png)i am using java azure functions in that i want get image from postman Form-data but unable to get image in correct format and the image size were increased  but it can done in postman binary with correct format and in actual sizebut in my work i want to get image through postman form-data

```
@FunctionName("CreateItemImage")
    public HttpResponseMessage createItemImage(@HttpTrigger(name = "request", methods = {
            HttpMethod.POST }, route = "menuimage", authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<byte[]> request,
            ExecutionContext context) {

        String connectionString = "keys";
        String containerName = "menuitemimage";
        String blobName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        String contentType = "image/jpeg";
        String localPath = "D:/Photo/three/"+blobName+".jpeg"; 
        
           
        try {
            byte[] imageBytes= request.getBody();

            if (imageBytes == null|| imageBytes.length == 0) {
                return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
                        .body("Image content is missing in the request.").build();
            }
            
             Path localFilePath = Paths.get(localPath);
                Files.write(localFilePath, imageBytes);

            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(connectionString)
                    .buildClient();
            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(containerName);
            BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(blobName);

            ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);

            byte[] md5Hash = calculateMD5Hash(imageBytes);

            BlobHttpHeaders headers = new BlobHttpHeaders().setContentType(contentType).setContentMd5(md5Hash);

            blobClient.upload(inputStream, imageBytes.length);
            blobClient.setHttpHeaders(headers);

            context.getLogger().info("Image uploaded successfully with Content-Type: " + contentType);

            return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK)
                    .body("Image uploaded successfully " +blobClient.getBlobUrl())
                    [](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcCZL.png)
                    .build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            context.getLogger().severe("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Error: " + e.getMessage())
                    .build();
        }
        
        
    }
    private byte[] calculateMD5Hash(byte[] data) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.update(data);
        return md.digest();

    }
```

i want to upload image in postman form-data with correct size and format and not only store image in blob storage i store the upcoming image from postman in local it also not correct format but working with binary

Answer (score 0):

I have made some little changes to the above code Azure Function is configured to accept `multipart/form-data` content. You can do this by specifying the correct `consumes` value in your `@HttpTrigger` annotation.

**BlobTriggerJava:**

```java
public HttpResponseMessage createItemImage(
    @HttpTrigger(
        name = "request",
        methods = { HttpMethod.POST },
        route = "menuimage",
        authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS,
        consumes = "multipart/form-data"
    ) HttpRequestMessage<FormData> request, ExecutionContext context) {

    String connectionString = "your_connection_string";
    String containerName = "menuitemimage";
    String blobName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    String contentType = "image/jpeg";

    try {
        FormData formData = request.getBody();
        
        if (!formData.containsKey("image")) {
            return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
                .body("Image is missing in the form-data request.").build();
        }

        // Get the image data from the form-data
        byte[] imageBytes = formData.get("image").get();

        // Your code to store the image in localPath, blob storage, or any other processing

        return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK)
            .body("Image uploaded successfully " + blobClient.getBlobUrl())
            .build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        context.getLogger().severe("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            .body("Error: " + e.getMessage())
            .build();
    }
}
```

**Dependency:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.functions</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-functions-java-library</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

- The `get("image").get()` method retrieves the image data from the form-data with the key "image."

[image]

In Postman, when you make a POST request with the "multipart/form-data" content type, include a key named "test" and attach your image file to it the test image will be correctly processed by your Azure Function.

[image]

In container:
[image]

Comment: @Pradeep S, This above dependency provides the `@FunctionName`, `@HttpTrigger`, and `@FromData` annotations, which you can use to define your Azure Functions.